# What pre- and/or postprocessing techniques to use on images before calculating disparity map

Tags: opencv, image-processing, disparity-mapping

I'm implementing the SGM algorithm to calculate the disparity from 2 rectified images (the Cones dataset from Middlebury's stereo page).

I have compared my results with those from OpenCV's StereoSGBM implementation and the both the results seem to be noisy. However, when I run the images through the python example "stereo_matcher.py", the results seem to be completely different and much better:

[My implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b88pm.jpg)

[OpenCV StereoSGBM's compute method with default parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV72K.jpg)

[OpenCV stereo_matcher.py's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgaG.png)

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I seem to be doing wrong. I think there are some pre- and/or postprocessing steps I need to apply, but I'm not sure which ones.

Comment: how large is your window? The smaller your window the noisier your result.

Comment: Yep, I reimplemented the algorithm and this time incorporated a block of pixels (vs single pixels as I did originally). I'm still in the process of implementing a larger block for larger images and thus finding the appropriate block size according to the image size, but I think that really was the problem.